# css border is working differently for various values

Tags: css

I was working on total width of a div in html.When I was practising I found this behaviour of border
first let Me show you My code

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", getEvent);

function getEvent() {
  console.log("clicked");
  console.log(document.querySelector(".container").offsetWidth);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  this is container div
</div>
```

The total_widths of the "container" for various border values are as shown below

| width | padding | border | total_width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100px | 50px | 1px | 202 (as expected) |
| 100px | 50px | 2px | 203 (204 is the expected value) |
| 100px | 50px | 3px | 205 (206 is the expected value) |
| 100px | 50px | 4px | 208 (as expected) |
| 100px | 50px | 10px | 219 (220px is the |
| 100px | 50px | 20px | 240 (as expected) |
| 100px | 50px | 30px | 259 (260px is the expected value) |
| 100px | 50px | 40px | 280 (as expected) |

why border is behaving like this?

Comment: This appears to work as expected for me (using your snippet), have you checked to see if it's browser/platform specific?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your errors. I am testing in FF and I get 220px in your example.

Comment: I am getting these values both on firefox and chrome

Comment: @maththisivacharan I have updated the code in answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other issue that is effecting your results. But I think in your case you need the results should be exact. So for that:-

You are using **offsetWidth** property. It gives result in integer. For fractional and exact results, use **getBoundingClientRect** method. It return the the lot of details. You can get the width using **getBoundingClientRect().width**.

You can update this part of code:-

```
console.log(document.querySelector(".container"). getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

It will include the padding and border also. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: but because borders of both left and right are added to the width We always get even number.so that value always should be integer.but why is this happening?

Comment: @maththisivacharan Did you try the getBoundingClientRect().width ??